# Flutter animation optimization: (one AnimationController + multiple animations+ bigger widget) vs (multiple widgets with their own controllers)

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I have different animations inside my Card widget.

Which way is better for optimization purposes:

- create one Stateful Card widget with one AnimationController, multiple Animations and multiple AnimationBulders in build method. Like this:

  ```
  class _MyWidgetState extends State<Heart> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      Anima`enter code here`tionController _controller;
      Animation<Color> _colorAnimation1;
      Animation<double> _sizeAnimation1; 
      Animation<Color> _colorAnimation2;
      Animation<double> _sizeAnimation2; 
      Animation<Color> _textAnimation3;
      Animation<double> _paddingAnimation3;
  ```
- create 3 different widgets with their own states and controllers?

Comment: both approaches are pretty much the same, no big difference in the performance

Comment: btw, flutter uses a lot built-in widgets working in both modes: `*Transiton` vs `Animated*`, like: `AlignTransition` / `ScaleTransition` vs `AnimatedAlign` / `AnimatedScale`